# How to make iPython follow the terminal's theme?

Tags: linux, terminal, powershell, themes

Using Windows Terminal, I have set a theme for both PowerShell and Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL, but why is that iPython follows the theme for the former, but falls back to a sort of "Breeze" in Linux?

[image: iPython on PowerShell]
[image: iPython on Ubuntu WSL]

I'm sure this is not a problem with the version, since I get a similar result when using an updated iPython on Linux proper, also getting that "default" theme over the terminal's:

[image: iPython on Linux]

Why does this happen? How can I make iPython follow my terminal's theme when in Linux environments?

---

**EDIT:** including the Windows Terminal profile as requested.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    // Add custom actions and keybindings to this array.
    // To unbind a key combination from your defaults.json, set the command to "unbound".
    // To learn more about actions and keybindings, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-keybindings
    "actions":
    [
        // Copy and paste are bound to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V in your defaults.json.
        // These two lines additionally bind them to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.
        // To learn more about selection, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-selection
        {
            "command":
            {
                "action": "copy",
                "singleLine": false
            },
            "keys": "ctrl+c"
        },
        {
            "command": "paste",
            "keys": "ctrl+v"
        },
        // Press Ctrl+Shift+F to open the search box
        {
            "command": "find",
            "keys": "ctrl+shift+f"
        },
        // Press Alt+Shift+D to open a new pane.
        // - "split": "auto" makes this pane open in the direction that provides the most surface area.
        // - "splitMode": "duplicate" makes the new pane use the focused pane's profile.
        // To learn more about panes, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-panes
        {
            "command":
            {
                "action": "splitPane",
                "split": "auto",
                "splitMode": "duplicate"
            },
            "keys": "alt+shift+d"
        }
    ],
    "alwaysShowTabs": true,
    "copyFormatting": "none",
    "copyOnSelect": true,
    "defaultProfile": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "initialCols": 150,
    "initialRows": 35,
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            "fontFace": "Roboto Mono"
        },
        "list":
        [
            {
                "colorScheme": "Spacedust",
                "commandline": "powershell.exe",
                "cursorShape": "filledBox",
                "experimental.retroTerminalEffect": false,
                "fontFace": "Code New Roman",
                "fontSize": 16,
                "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Windows PowerShell",
                "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
                "useAcrylic": false
            },
            {
                "colorScheme": "AtelierSulphurpool",
                "commandline": "cmd.exe",
                "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Command Prompt"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
            },
            {
                "colorScheme": "Spacedust",
                "cursorShape": "filledBox",
                "fontFace": "MesloLGS NF",
                "fontSize": 15,
                "guid": "{07b52e3e-de2c-5db4-bd2d-ba144ed6c273}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Ubuntu-20.04",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
                "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
                "suppressApplicationTitle": true,
                "tabTitle": "Ubuntu (WSL)"
            }
        ]
    },
    "schemes":
    [
        {
            "background": "#202746",
            "black": "#202746",
            "blue": "#3D8FD1",
            "brightBlack": "#6B7394",
            "brightBlue": "#898EA4",
            "brightCyan": "#9C637A",
            "brightGreen": "#293256",
            "brightPurple": "#DFE2F1",
            "brightRed": "#C76B29",
            "brightWhite": "#F5F7FF",
            "brightYellow": "#5E6687",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#22A2C9",
            "foreground": "#979DB4",
            "green": "#AC9739",
            "name": "AtelierSulphurpool",
            "purple": "#6679CC",
            "red": "#C94922",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#979DB4",
            "yellow": "#C08B30"
        },
        {
            "background": "#0A1E24",
            "black": "#6E5346",
            "blue": "#0F548B",
            "brightBlack": "#684C31",
            "brightBlue": "#67A0CE",
            "brightCyan": "#83A7B4",
            "brightGreen": "#AECAB8",
            "brightPurple": "#FF8A3A",
            "brightRed": "#FF8A3A",
            "brightWhite": "#FEFFF1",
            "brightYellow": "#FFC878",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#06AFC7",
            "foreground": "#ECF0C1",
            "green": "#5CAB96",
            "name": "Spacedust",
            "purple": "#E35B00",
            "red": "#E35B00",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#F0F1CE",
            "yellow": "#E3CD7B"
        }
    ],
    "wordDelimiters": " /\\()\"'-.,:;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}~?\u2502"
}
```

Comment: What version of Windows Terminal do you have installed exactly?

Comment: It's 1.8.1521.0, but should that be relevant?

Comment: @manielpqueiroz - It certainly is.  Can you upgrade to the current version (1.9) and [edit] your question to include your profile file.

Comment: @Ramhound, AFAIK, version 1.9 is still in pre-release and thus only available to "Preview" terminal users (not my case). I'm also led to believe this *has* to be something with iPython's default configuration files on Linux, since neither the WSL nor the actual Linux versions depicted conform to the respective terminal's theme. Either way, I've updated the question with the profile file.

Comment: I would replace  *AtelierSulphurpool* with *Spacedust* for Command Prompt and/or define a iPython profile explicitly